# Quantile function for mixed von Mises distributions

Tags: r, statistics, distribution, quantile

I want to calculate the quantile function for a mixture of von Mises distribution. I am using the package *circular* in R, which supports the density, the cumulative probability and sampling from such a model by *dmixedvonmises()*, *pmixedvonmises()* and *rmixedvonmises()*, respectively. However, there are no qmixedvonmises() (Which is what I want). 
For a single von Mises distribution, they all exist; *rvonmises()*, *dvonmises()*, *pvonmises()* and *qvonmises()*. 
Is it difficult to get the function for the quantiles of a mixture of von Mises distributions (given that all model parameters are known)? Can anyone help me with how this function would look like? 
Are there other packages in R that provides this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even in such convenient cases as with normal distribution there is no closed-form expression for that. However, we may use numerical methods.

```
library(circular)
qmixedvonmises <- function(p, mu1, mu2, kappa1, kappa2, prop) {
  fun <- function(q) pmixedvonmises(q, mu1, mu2, kappa1, kappa2, prop) - p
  suppressWarnings(uniroot(fun, c(0, 2 * pi - 1e-8))$root)
}
qmixedvonmises(0.05, mu1 = circular(0), mu2 = circular(pi), kappa1 = 15, kappa2 = 15, prop = 0.5)
# [1] 0.06599235
qmixedvonmises(0.95, mu1 = circular(0), mu2 = circular(pi), kappa1 = 15, kappa2 = 15, prop = 0.5)
# [1] 6.217193
```

For more detail see, e.g., [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/177049/10172), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/157388/10172), and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/14481/10172).

`qmixedvonmises` exploits the fact that `pmixedvonmises` is already available and simply solves numerically for such `q` that

```
pmixedvonmises(q) == p
```